# Need help regarding a masm32 program

Tags: masm32

I'm just a beginner in assembly programming. This is the code I was trying, but it keeps returning an error.

Error is:

```
F:\masm32\bin>ml PRINTSTRING.ASM
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.
Assembling: PRINTSTRING.ASM
PRINTSTRING.ASM(35) : fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : data
```

My program is:

```
;Print a String

data segment
;add your data here
mymessage db"Enter your data $"
end

stack segment
dw 128 dup(0)
end

code segment
Start:

;Set Segment Registers
    mov     ax,OFFSET mymessage
    mov     ds,ax
    mov     es,ax
    lea     dx,mymessage
    mov     ah,mymessage
    mov     ah,9
    int     21h

    mov     ah,1
    int     21h

    mov     ax,4c00h
    int     21h

end
end Start
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.model small` as the first line.

Comment: F:\masm32\bin>ml PRINTSTRING.ASM
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: PRINTSTRING.ASM

Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5 1994
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1993.  All rights reserved.

Object Modules [.obj]: PRINTSTRING.obj
Run File [PRINTSTRING.exe]: "PRINTSTRING.exe"
List File [nul.map]: NUL
Libraries [.lib]:
Definitions File [nul.def]:
LINK : warning L4021: no stack segment
LINK : warning L4038: program has no starting address                  

@gunner

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you doing 16bit DOS Assembly?  32Bit Assembly is a bit easier!

This works:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
mymessage db 'Enter your data $'

.code
start:
    mov     ax, @data
    mov     ds, ax

    lea     dx, mymessage 
    mov     ah, 09h
    int     21h

    mov     ah, 1h
    int     21h

    mov     ax, 4c00h
    int     21h
end start
```

Assemble and link:

```
D:\Projects\DOS>ml /c prateek.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.15.8803
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-2000.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: prateek.asm

D:\Projects\DOS>link16 prateek.obj

Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5 1994
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1993.  All rights reserved.

Run File [prateek.exe]:
List File [nul.map]:
Libraries [.lib]:
Definitions File [nul.def]:

D:\Projects\DOS>
```

It runs fine in DOSBox

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
data segment

;add your data here

mymessage db"Enter your data $"

data ends

stack segment

dw 128 dup(0)

stack ends

code segment

Start:


;Set Segment Registers

    mov     ax,OFFSET mymessage

    mov     ds,ax

    mov     es,ax

    lea     dx,mymessage

    mov     ah,mymessage

    mov     ah,9

    int     21h


    mov     ah,1

    int     21h


    mov     ax,4c00h

    int     21h


code ends

end
```

Comment: Can you please add some explenation to your answer?